# Differentiability of a function of 3 variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm stuck into a problem, that I think it's not too hard, but I didn't figured it out. It asks me to prove that a given function is differentiable or not:
$$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{(x^2y^2)^p(1-\cos(z))^q}{x^2+y^2+z^2},&\rm {if}\,(x,y,z)\ne (0,0,0)\\0,&\rm{if}\,(x,y,z)=(0,0,0).\end{cases}$$
My problem is how to generalize the analysis for values different from $$p=1$$ and $$q=1$$ (I've already made an analysis for this values, but i want to generalize it)
*  $$p>0$$ and $$q>0$$
Thanks in advance for the attention and any help :)

Comment: It is obviously differentiable elsewhere but for the origin. Thus, I guess you want to investigate the case of differentiability at the origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $1-\cos(z) \leq \frac{z^2}{2} \leq z^2$ for all $z$. Given that $p$ and $q$ are both positive, hence $x^p$ and $x^q$ are monotonically increasing on the positive reals, we also have that

$$\frac{(x^2y^2)^p(1-\cos(z))^q}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \leq \frac{(x^2y^2)^p(z^2)^q}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

All three partials at $(0,0,0)$ evaluate to $0$, so all that's left to prove differentiability is to show the limit

$$\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to\mathbf{0}} \frac{|f(\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{0}) - \mathbf{0}\cdot \mathbf{h}|}{||\mathbf{h}||} = 0$$

Plugging things in and converting to spherical coordinates:

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)} \frac{|xy|^{2p}|1-\cos(z)|^q}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \leq \lim_{r\to 0^+} r^{4p+2q-3}|\sin^2(\theta)\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)|^{2p}|cos(\theta)|^{2q}$$

The angular function on the right is bounded, therefore by squeeze theorem if the limit is to be $0$, we arrive at the condition that $2p+q > \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you :), I understood the steps, but in the last one it should be $$r^(4p+2q-3)$$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @FernandoSantiago Yes, you are right, I will fix it

Comment: @FernandoSantiago I want to point out that this is not a proof of that being a necessary condition. One would have to violate the condition and show the limit does not exist in that case.